# what does Inflating StatefullWidget mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, statefulwidget

State objects are created by the framework by calling the StatefulWidget.createState method when inflating a StatefulWidget to insert it into the tree. Here What does inflating StatefulWidget mean?

Comment: You can check flutter docs from here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: I took  this Statement"State objects are created by the framework by calling the StatefulWidget.createState method when inflating a StatefulWidget to insert it into the tree." from flutter.dev .But here what does exactly mean by inflating StatefullWidget mean?

Answer (score 3):

Here, "inflating" means "adding". `createState()` helps us in adding(inflating) state(information) to our StatefulWidget.

When we create a widget(say Container widget), we add other properties to it(like height, width and background-color).

> We can say that we're "inflating" our Container widget with height,
> width and background-color.